# Sudden MySQL connection issue

Tags: mysql, max-connections

We have almost 60 network guys working via a proxy server, developing on one Linux-based in-house server.

Suddenly, it is saying to everyone:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: 
Too many connections in XXXXXXXX FILE NAMES
```

We have cleared `tmp` folders as well, but after restarting we face the same issue.

What is the solution to this error?

Comment: Can you log into MySQL and run 'SHOW PROCESSLIST'? That should get you started figuring out what's using all the connections.

Comment: I added

max_connections=5000
max_user_connections=500

But it did not resolve this issue :(

Comment: SHOW PROCESSLIST is showing nothing

Comment: Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

Comment: Did you restart your server process or something?

Comment: Does the problem persist? Are there any long running queries or aren't connections closed properly?

Comment: It sounds like you're using phpMyAdmin and it can't connect either. This page explains how to connect to MySQL from the command line: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-connect-to-my-mysql-database-server-using-command-line-and-php/. You'll most likely need to connect as the MySQL root user to get around the 'out of connections' errors. There is a connection reserved for root that should be available unless your applications are connecting as root (very dangerous practice).

Comment: Yes restarting after every change.

Scenario is that everyone on proxy just visit their websites front end which opens connection with mySQL. Still problem persists...

Comment: @JohnP: That's not the case, as I have just described in latest comment that every website which is being developed by each user goes visited by them when I asked and by included connection file, each website opens a connect... which comes later with refresh as "maximum connections" and when if visit PHPMYADMIN then it says in message "Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed."

Comment: It has been working perfectly from so many months ... why it is now...???

Comment: Setting up max_connections and max_user_connections did work but after restarting the server :)

Thanks everybody... Love your support :)

Answer (score 1):

SET @@GLOBAL.wait_timeout = 30;

Have your users disconnect when they are through.

Do not have more than 20 for MaxClients in Apache.